# Is Portal 2 available on Mac?

Tags: macos, portal-2

Is Portal 2 available on Mac? If it is then I would buy it, because it is my favorite game.

Comment: This seems like a rather simple thing to use a search engine for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Portal 2 is available for Mac. If you search for it on Steam, you will see the Apple logo, which indicates it is available for Mac.

[image: mac icon]

The system requirements are also listed on the store page for Portal 2.

[image: system requirements]

Comment: Works well, too.